# How to use preg_replace_callback

Tags: preg-replace-callback

I am trying to replace the 2nd occurrence of the $target_str.

If someone could explain how preg_replace_callback works I would appreciate it. 
I don't understand the function($match) part. How do I set it so it matches the 2nd occurrence and only replaces that string?

I have the code (but it doesn't work as I want it to).

`$replacement_params['target_str'] = "[\n]";
    $replacement_params['replacement_str'] = "\n<ads media=googleAds1 />\n";
$target_str = $this->params['target_str'];
$replacement_str = $this->params['replacement_str'];
$num_matches;`

```
$i = 0;
$new_text = preg_replace_callback("/".$target_str."/U", 
            function ( $match ) {
                if ( $i === 1 ) {
                    return $replacement_str;
                } else {
                    return $match[0];
                }
                $i++;
            } , $article_text, 1, $num_matches );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Updated***

Using built-in counter variable of `preg_replace_callback`:

```
$new_text = preg_replace_callback("/$target_str/U", 
                function($matches) use (&$count, $replacement_str)
                {
                    $count++;
                    return ($count == 2) ? $replacement_str : $matches[0];
                } , $article_text, -1, $count);
```

Comment: It isn't inserting the replacement text. How do I debug this to find out what isn't working? Why do I need to Increment if I just want the 2nd match? I added what the variables equal to the original question incase it makes a difference. Thanks

Comment: @LTech Updated the answer. You need to have a counter otherwise you can't figure our in which state you're in.

Comment: I've tried to copy and paste in your code and I still can't get anything to happen. Is "replacement" a string or a variable? and "/t/U" can that also be a variable?

Comment: It wasn't working b/c of an if( $num_matches>0) later on in the code which I removed. Thanks so much it is working now.